# jQuery text attribute selector

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-selectors

I am trying to use the text attribute as a selector, but I can't quite grasp the behaviour, would really appreciate if someone could explain. For example given `<span class="span_class"><a class="a_class">text</a></span>`, `$('a.a_class').text()` gives "text" as expected. However `$('a.a_class[text]')` wouldn't match any elements, and neither would `$('span.span_class > a.a_class[text]')`, but `$('span.span_class* > a.a_class[text]')` would (although not in IE). 
The only workaround I can think of for IE, is loop through all anchors contained in a span, use .text() on each and match it against a certain criteria, but it seems slower than using in-built selectors. Anyone have better ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what about using a custom selector

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.extend($.expr[':'], {
    notext: function(elem, i, attr){
      return( $(elem).text() === "" );
    }
  });        
});
```

**Synopsis**

```
$('span:notext').remove();
```

you might even want to create a selector that handles Regular Expressions like

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
   'content': function(elem, i, attr){      
     return( RegExp(attr[3]).test($(elem).text()) );
   }
});
```

**Synopsis**

```
$('span:content(^api_)').remove();
```

would select and remove all spans which text begins with `api_`

Comment: I'll leave the same comment here: Unless you *need* a regular expression, use `.indexOf()`, it's *much* faster, and when you're talking about selectors, especially on potentially large numbers of elements, speed matters.

Comment: Yep, I adapted it to use indexOf as well. Thanks for help everyone.

Comment: @Nick: I wanted to create it like so, a selector which uses regular expressions.

Comment: Probably better to use `$.text(elem)` instead of `$(elem).text()` -- the former is much faster because it avoids constructing a new jQ instance.

Comment: @J-P - `$.text()` operates on an array, it'd actually be `$.text([this])`, but good point on performance :)

Answer (score 3):

This is because 'text' in this case is not an attribute. It is the content of the element.

You're looking for the `:contains()` selector:

```
$('a.a_class:contains(text)');
```

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Keep in mind that this selector will match any part of the string. `contains(foo)` will match "foo bar" as well.

If you want an exact match of the entire text string, you could use `filter()`

```
$('a.a_class').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == "text";
});
```

---

**EDIT:**

To find elements whose content starts with a value, you could use a regular expression inside the `filter()`:

```
$('a.a_class').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().indexOf( "tex" ) >= 0;
});
```

**EDIT:** Updated to use `indexOf()` instead of regex as recommended by @Nick.

Comment: Hmm ok. What I was looking for was "Starts with" though, and `$('span.span_class* > a.a_class[text^="tex"]')` was working great, until I tested it with IE.

Comment: @Shagglez - I didn't realize that would work at all. I guess I'd use the `filter()` option with regex to figure out if the text start with "tex".

Comment: @Shagglez - You can use what @patrick has, just replace `return $(this).text() == "text";` with `return $(this).text().indexOf("text") ===0;` for a "start-with" check.

Comment: Unless you *need* a regular expression, use `.indexOf()`, it's *much* faster, and when you're talking about selectors, especially on potentially large numbers of elements, speed matters.