# Filtering the data according to Index(A B C D....) using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have Small requirement like this

A B C D E ....

When i click on the A

The Table data will have to show only Name starting with A
like 
Apple
Axe
Ant

(Dont say filter the database)
How can i show the rows which having the names starts with A only

Thanking u

Comment: please provide some code , then any one can answer the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `filter` -

```
$("table tr").filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().substring(0, 1).toLowerCase() != 'a';
}).hide();
```

This would only work if the 'name' column was the first column in your table. If you wanted to look for a specific column in the table you could do something like this -

```
$("table tr").filter(function() {
  return $(this).children('td').eq(0).text().substring(0, 1).toLowerCase() != 'a';
}).hide();
```

`eq(0)` could be changed to point at your column of choice.

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/XHg5v/

Comment: Yes its full-fill  my requirement

Answer (score 0):

**Working example**

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
 <body>
  <ul id=hd>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>all</li>
  <li>b</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id=content>
<li >apple</li>
<li >bre</li>
<li >bbb</li>
<li >ape</li>
<li >aman</li>
<li >bcd</li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$('#hd>li').click(function(){
    var key = $(this).text();
    if(key == 'all') {   
        $('#content>li').show();
        return;
    }
    $('#content>li').hide();
    $('#content>li:content(^' + key +')').show()
})

$.extend($.expr[':'], {
   'content': function(elem, i, attr){      
     return( RegExp(attr[3]).test($(elem).text()) );
   }
});

//-->
</script>
 </body>
```

Used [jQuery text attribute selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060847/jquery-text-attribute-selector) . Assuming all the data are displayed in li.

Answer (score 0):

See this http://echarp.org/filterTable

it uses a **TEXT BOX** to **FILTER** the contents of the **TABLE**

You can manually call the event which is **Firing** on **ONCHANGE** event of **TEXTBOX** by calling in **ONCLICK** of **A**.

http://www.vonloesch.de/node/23
This shows the details of using the **FILTER**

Answer (score 0):

```
$('span').click(function(){

var letter = $(this).html();

$('tr').each(function(){

var val = $('this').children('td').val();

var first_letter = val.split('')[0];

if(first_letter == letter){

   $('this').hide();

}
else{

  $('this').show();
}
});
```

assume that A,B,C,D are in spans

```
<span>A</span>
```

and one table row has one td